# Alien vixen on the hunt for sperm donor rewards

Tags: biology, biochemistry, sex

Sorry for the slightly X-rated question, I have an alien vixen, like a bounty hunter but her game is those rarest genomes for the sperm donation clinic, she can lure her males but the issue is about contamination, she cant let them know she is filling a container with their sperm so it has to be discrete but she knows she cant let them see any containers for the task.

So the question is: how much of her bodily fluids, her saliva or an ejaculation in her nether parts will contaminate or ruin her sample. As saliva and bodily fluids can break down sperm, how can she allow the normal love making process but still collect a viable sample? and what are her limitations or allowing other bodily fluids to be involved?

Assume she is of human DNA with human DNA being collected or something similar and not foreign with different chemical break downs.

Answer (score 4):

**DNA will perservere.**

Some logistical issues first

1:  The genome of the organism is not represented in the sperm.  Sperm are haploid products of meiosis and so the genome of the male organisms will have been meiotically shuffled.  If she wants to collect rare whole genomes she does not want sperm.  But maybe she is after rare gene variants.

2:  If for the purposes of your story she wants sperm, she could ask her partner to use a condom.  Or offer one to him, because despite her alien vixenness she has cooties.   Condoms are a proven way to keep donor body fluid separate.

3:  Genomic analysis is possible on tiny cheek swabs or long dried samples collected from ancient crime scenes.  It will not take much material to sequence.  Semen could be fine for this because DNA analysis for criminal cases or paternity analysis looks at just a few highly variable genes such that the combination is likely specific to an individual.

4:  If the concern is that her genes are contaminating the specimen that is fine.  It can even be mostly her DNA because that is often the case for crimes.  The sequencing software will turn up as many as 4 versions of a given gene (because we diploid critters can have 2 different versions).  Hers are known and so are ignored.  If the software turns up only genes she has then she shares those genes with the male donor; they are both human so that will happen often.

As regards the prospects of gathering genetic material from somewhere other than sperm, we are shedding genomes all the time.  She can get it from his shed hairs or off a coffee cup he drinks from.

Comment: But your answer is mostly crime related or to recognise a genome, enough to inseminate is the issue.

Comment: There is also a female version of the condom, and if secrecy in collection is required, this might be better for your cause. If you eliminate spermicides and have an acceptably neutral lubricant (possibly one that functions as a preservative), it should work fine. Sounds like you want viable sperm (or close). Then, her genetic contamination is irrelevant (since the sperm are in a separate cell). The marks might wonder about the centrifuges and -80 freezer in the bedroom, though...

Comment: @DWKraus a female condom is very much visible from the outside, as it's meant to protect from the entrance onwards and requires the grip so not to be pushed fully inside and losing effectiveness. It is also quite different in feeling compared to no condom. There is technology that could be adapted a bit to make an "invisible" female condom, but there is still the possibility the male could feel it. Though I suspect most targets won't mind at that moment and would gladly think it's just birth control and not a collection mechanism.

Comment: @RogerHarris - I misunderstood.  I was focusing on the genome collection aspect and did not realize she intended to make babies from these donors.  Then the condom.   There was a Law and Order episode where a malefactor hired a sex worker to collect sperm in this way in order to frame the donor for rape of the malefactor.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure the problem is COLLECTING an uncompromised sample, but in RETRIEVING the sample uncompromised.

How does this vixen guarantee the integrity of the sample? How promiscuous is she? What 'cleansing' actions are implemented between sample recoveries?

And how vested is she in devoting her body to the cause?

Having a hysterectomy, and replacing it with an artificial vessel, would completely solve your problems, but of course make pregnancy impossible for your vixen. It is not hard to imagine a vessel that is lined of synthetic material that is a natural barrier between the collected sample and the internal environment of the vixen. If the vessel were completely sealed except for the cervix end, then a suction device could be used for extracting the deposited sperm. Likewise, a cleansing bath could be squirted in between sample acquisition. In fact, it could be hypothesized that preservatives could be inserted into the vessel ahead of time to better preserve the samples.

Comment: At no point in  my question dis i ask about collection apparatus, the question is about fluid contamination and levels of degradation. What preservatives do you have in mind?

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the 'she can lure her males but the issue is about contamination, she cant let them know she is filling a container with their sperm so it has to be discrete but she knows she cant let them see any containers for the task.' part, Not being a reproductive specialist, I can not specifically recommend preservatives, but here is an article that might help. https://www.babyhopes.com/blogs/fertility/sperm-survive

Answer (score 2):

**She can collect enough**

Lets take a real world example. DNA can be harvested in crime scenes from just droplets found on a body. Don't get me wrong. Getting a clear sample of DNA from crime scenes is difficult. It is often contaminated by other sources, which makes it difficult to identify the correct DNA. So it is more of a question "who's DNA is it" than a degraded bunch of unrecognisable DNA. We can get a good DNA sample from this residue.

That being said, you have a more or less ideal scenario to collect it. You can have them wear a condom, which will concentrate the desired DNA material on one place, or try to get it out of her herself, which might contaminate it, but won't be too much of a problem. You can just take several samples and remove the DNA samples that match the alien her DNA. The remaining one should have the desired DNA.

Lastly you have one more advantage. A sperm cell can be identified by microscope, removing the guesswork when you take a sample. The DNA should be safe inside the cell  sperm cells are actually one of the first things ever viewed behind a microscope, which tells you something about science.

So with a large sample of DNA at your disposal and the ability to just take several samples just in case it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The problem is having a large enough sample that hasn't been degraded.

Comment: @Roger_Harris you don't need much for a sample. That's the point. A single drop can have a hundred million sperms inside. Even when they're dead they can give DNA. not all will die from the acidity. Sperm can be locked inside a congealing drop and stay alive. They can get DNA samples from the leftover blood and seamen. And again, she can just use condoms to prevent practically all contamination problems.